# open() function in C

Tags: c, directory

After opening a directory, I wanna check if a command (such as ls) resides within a given directory but open returns an integer i think.. after tokenization, I'm left with some directories... so what can i do?? I was told to use only open() function :((

```
int       Account_Master;
    .  .  .
  Account_Master = open ("accounts.dat", O_RDONLY);
  if (Account_Master >0) {
    printf ("Open succeeded.\n");
```

this is the example i used.. whats the point of opening a file if no use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integer returned can be given to other functions, such as `read`, `fstat`, and `close`. If you just want to check whether a file exists, use [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stat):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  struct stat statInfo;
  char* fn = argc>1 ? argv[1] : "/bin/ls";
  int res = stat(fn, &statInfo);
  if (res != 0) {
     printf("File %s does not exist.\n", fn);
     return 1;
  }
  if (statInfo.st_mode & S_IXUSR) {
     printf("Owner can execute the file %s\n", fn);
     return 0;
  }
  printf("File %s is there, but not executable.\n", fn);
  return 2;
}
```

If you don't want to check a single file, but a whole directory, have a look at [`readdir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) instead.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer.. is there an example of it that I can apply it in my code

Comment: If you want to check for existence only, `access()` is easier, since you don't need to allocate a `struct stat`

Answer (score 1):

Homework? If you're only allowed to use `open` then the solution is to try to open the file. If the call succeeded then the file exists. If it failed, then it doesn't exist.

Edit: strictly speaking, you should also check that `errno == ENOENT`. Otherwise there was another kind of error preventing you from opening the file.

Don't forget to close the fd returned if the call succeeded.

Btw, the example in your question is not completely correct. open can also succeed by returning 0. It's uncommon though since fd 0 is usually already taken.